# JavaGit Api not Working on Windows

Tags: java, git, netbeans, git-log, changelog

```
package modifiedlines;

import edu.nyu.cs.javagit.api.DotGit;
import edu.nyu.cs.javagit.api.JavaGitConfiguration;
import edu.nyu.cs.javagit.api.JavaGitException;
import edu.nyu.cs.javagit.api.WorkingTree;
import edu.nyu.cs.javagit.api.commands.GitLogResponse;
import edu.nyu.cs.javagit.api.commands.GitStatus;
import edu.nyu.cs.javagit.api.commands.GitStatusOptions;
import edu.nyu.cs.javagit.api.commands.GitStatusResponse;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @

    author aryan000
     */

public class UseGit {

    private static File repositoryDirectory;
    private static DotGit dotGit;

    public static void main(String s[]) throws JavaGitException, IOException
    {   

        File f = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\git.exe");

        if(!f.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("does not exist");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("exists  at " + f.getPath());
        JavaGitConfiguration.setGitPath("C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin");
        System.out.println("Git version : " + JavaGitConfiguration.getGitVersion());
//        repositoryDirectory = new File("/home/aryan000/Desktop/retrofit");


        repositoryDirectory = new File("/home/aryan000/Desktop/changeprone/changeprone");

        System.out.println("Git Repository Location : " + repositoryDirectory.getAbsolutePath());

        //get the instance of the dotGit Object
        dotGit = DotGit.getInstance(repositoryDirectory);

//        System.out.println("checking what i have got ");
//        GitLogResponse.CommitFile com ;
//        com = (GitLogResponse.CommitFile) dotGit.getLog();
//        
//        System.out.println(com);

         WorkingTree wt = dotGit.getWorkingTree();
         File workingTreePath = wt.getPath();
         GitStatus gitStatus = new GitStatus();
         GitStatusResponse status = gitStatus.status(workingTreePath);

         System.out.println("status is : " + status);

         File anotherFileDir = new File("/home/aryan000/Desktop/retrofit/test.txt");
        GitStatusOptions options = new GitStatusOptions();
        options.setOptOnly(true);
        status = gitStatus.status(workingTreePath);

        System.out.println("status is : " + status);







        System.out.println("----- Print log to see our commit -----");
        for (GitLogResponse.Commit c : dotGit.getLog()) {
            System.out.println("commit id is : " + c.getSha());
            System.out.println(" commit message is : " + c.getMessage());
            System.out.println(" author of the commit is : " + c.getAuthor());
            System.out.println(" date modified is : " + c.getDateString());
            System.out.println(" number of files changed is : " + c.getFiles());
            List<GitLogResponse.CommitFile> store = c.getFiles();
            if(store!=null)
            System.out.println("the number of files changed is : " + store.size());
            System.out.println("list of files changed is : " + c.getFilesChanged());

            System.out.println("total number of additions : " + c.getLinesDeleted());
            System.out.println("total number of merger : " + c.getMergeDetails());


        }

//        for(GitLogResponse.CommitFile c : dotGit.getLog())

    }
}
```

**Output is shown as :**

```
Exception in thread "main" edu.nyu.cs.javagit.api.JavaGitException: 100002: Invalid path to git specified. { path=[C:\Program Files\Git\bin] }
    at edu.nyu.cs.javagit.api.JavaGitConfiguration.setGitPath(JavaGitConfiguration.java:220)
    at edu.nyu.cs.javagit.api.JavaGitConfiguration.setGitPath(JavaGitConfiguration.java:247)
    at modifiedlines.UseGit.main(UseGit.java:40)
Caused by: edu.nyu.cs.javagit.api.JavaGitException: 100002: Invalid path to git specified.
    at edu.nyu.cs.javagit.api.JavaGitConfiguration.determineGitVersion(JavaGitConfiguration.java:81)
    at edu.nyu.cs.javagit.api.JavaGitConfiguration.setGitPath(JavaGitConfiguration.java:217)
    ... 2 more
Java Result: 1
```

My query is how to find git logs and the files changed due to a particular commit using a Java Program. 
Can any 1 help me in this.

**Please See :**  This code is working fine in Ubuntu i.e. no Path problem still I am unable to get the files changed during a commit. It is give me a List as a null.

Comment: The output is telling you what's wrong: `Invalid path to git specified. { path=[C:\Program Files\Git\bin] }`  Change that path to point to where you have the Git binaries installed.

Comment: @ Jim Garrison 

I have my git installed there only. I assume you are referring to git.exe installation folder. If I am mistaken. Please correct me

Comment: We cannot see the Javadoc for the classes you are using. Are you sure `JavaGitConfiguration.setGitPath("C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin")` is correct? Should it be `JavaGitConfiguration.setGitPath("C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\git.exe")`?

Comment: And BTW it does not "give you a List as null", it throws an Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was opened [a long time ago](https://github.com/bit-man/SwissArmyJavaGit/issues/13) and just fixed it. Please [give it a try](https://github.com/bit-man/SwissArmyJavaGit) , use master branch please, and let me know if it works for you.